# Why $\frac{1}{n}\mathcal{X}_{[0,n]}$ converges to zero in measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How can I directly prove that for any $\epsilon>0, \lim_n m\left\{x:|f_n(x)|>\epsilon\right\}=0?$

I have a confusion.
Let $\epsilon=1/2$ then $\left\{x:f_n(x)>1/2\right\}=[0,1]$ but $m[0,1]\not<1/2$

Let $\epsilon>0$ then $\left\{x:f_n(x)>\epsilon\right\}=[0,n]$ with $1/n>\epsilon$ then $m([0,n]\not<\epsilon$...
It's wrong?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have commented more on my post

Comment: @eraldcoil The value of $f_{n}$ changes for each $n$.  Please see my answer.  Your work is wrong because you said $\{x : f_{n}(x) > \frac{1}{2} \} = [0,1]$.  This isn't true for every $n$.  Just for $n = 1$.  It fails for $n = 2$, since $f_{2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,2]$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: All the reason. I did not think that the whole could be empty for n enough large. I forgot it...

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the values of $f_{n}(x) := \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[0,n]}(x)$.  This function can be equivalently expressed as $$f_{n}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & x \in [0,n] \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$

So, $f_{1}(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ everywhere else.  $f_{2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ on $[0,2]$ and $0$ everywhere else.  $f_{10}(x) = \frac{1}{10}$ on $[0,10]$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Clearly, $|f_{n}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for every $x$.  Now, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $m \in \Bbb N$ so that $\frac{1}{m} \leq \epsilon$, right?  Thus, $|f_{m}(x)| \leq \frac{1}{m} \leq \epsilon$.  Also, if $n \geq m$, then we also have $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{m} \leq \epsilon$.

What does that tell you about $|f_{n}(x)|$ in relation to $\epsilon$ for every $n \geq m$?  What does this imply about the set $\{x \mid |f_{n}(x)| > \epsilon \}$ for every $n \geq m$?

Comment: $\left\{x:f_n(x)>\epsilon\right\}=\emptyset$ for $n\geq m$

Comment: @eraldcoil Exactly!  That means it has measure 0!  So for every $n \geq m$, $m( \{x : f_{n}(x) > \epsilon \}) = 0$, which means $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} m( \{x : f_{n}(x) > \epsilon \}) = 0$, which is exactly what you wanted! :)

Answer (score 1):

Given $\epsilon>0$ you can find $N$ such that $N<n$ implies $1/n < \epsilon$, so the set you want to measure is empty.